# Joint distribution of non-central chi squared and standard Gaussian

Tags: normal-distribution, joint-distribution, chi-squared-distribution

Given $Z \sim N(0,1)$ and $Y \sim \chi^2_d (\lambda)$, such that $Correlation(Z,Y) = \rho$, find $E(ZY)$.

Assume $0 < d < 1$, so we cannot use $\chi^2_d (\lambda) = \chi^2_1 (\lambda) + \chi^2_{d-1}$, where $\chi^2_{d-1}$ is a central $\chi^2$ distribution with $d-1$ degrees of freedom.

Instead, we can use the following: For any $d > 0$, $\chi^2_d (\lambda) \sim \chi^2_{d + 2N}$, where $N \sim Poisson(\frac{\lambda}{2})$.

Thanks.

Comment: Hint: Use iterated expectations

Comment: You are missing the self-study tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The wording of the problem makes me think they want you to use iterated expectations. We have

$$Cov(Z,Y) = E[ZY] - E[Z]E[Y] = E[ZY]$$

Correlation is $$\rho = \dfrac{Cov(Z,Y)}{\sqrt{Var[Z]Var[Y]}}$$

combining we have $$E[ZY] = \rho\sqrt{Var[Y]}$$

$$\begin{align*}
Var[Y] &= E[Var[Y|N] + Var[E[Y|N]]\\
&= E[2(d+2N)] + Var[d+2N]\\
&= 2d+2\lambda + 2\lambda\\
&= 2d+4\lambda
\end{align*}$$

Note we could have gotten variance of $Y$ directly from knowing that the variance of a non-central chi-square ($\chi_d^2(\lambda))$ is $2(d+2\lambda)$.